# iOS 8.3 Keyboard (3rd party) hidden/missing in messages

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, bug, swiftkey

This happened to me on older iOS 8.x versions, but stopped for a while and came back when I upgraded to a newer iphone (from 5s to 6, with 8.3).

Seemingly randomly, certain times the keyboard just will not raise up in Messages (sometimes in other apps).

I'm using a third party keyboard, SwiftKey, but it happens to the standard keyboard as well. It also happens on a friends iPhone 6.

My currently solution for getting the keyboard back is quitting the app and relaunching, which is super annoying when trying to send a text.

Comment: You should wait for an update of SwiftKey Developer.

Comment: @KarloA.López, well like I said, this happens with the standard keyboard as well. I just happen to be using a third party keyboard right now.

Comment: I experience the exact same problem. It is now August 9th an iOS 8 is on its way out yet nobody seems to have done anything to fix this problem. It is quite frustrating.

Comment: This problem continues for me on iOS 9. Every keyboard I try has this issue. So I wonder if it's not an iOS problem.